# Null value inserted upon creating a new entry in a Firebase collection using Backfire

Tags: firebase

I'm using Backfire to create an 'index' collection for indexing newly registered users so that they can be used with Twitter's 'typeahead' library (https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js).

```
    var FireIndex = Backbone.Firebase.Collection.extend({
      model   : Backbone.Model,
      firebase: new Firebase(FirebaseUrl + '/index/')
    }),
    fireIndex = new FireIndex();

    var index = fireIndex.create({id: 1, last_name: 'Smith', first_name: 'John'});
```

Unfortunately, it seems like a 'null' value kept being inserted into the 'index' collection, as followed:

[null, null, {id: 1, ....}, {id:2, ....}]

The null value causes the typeahead to error out.

I have made sure that nothing being inserted is null and also tried seeding the 'index' collection, to no avail, with a 'false' value like the following:
{index: false}

The null value doesn't show up in the GUI version of the collection but would appear if accessed through the REST API, like so "https://mydb.firebaseio.com/index.json".

Any help is appreciated.

-Tony

Comment: Interesting - in what cases does the null value appear? The data stored in Firebase should always be an object, not an array.

Comment: The 'index' collection is completely blank.  I just tried importing an object directly into the collection and it's still producing an array with a null value. My security rule is as followed:   "index": {
      ".read": true,
      "$user_index": {
        //Newly registered user may create an index
        //User may update his index
        ".write": "(!data.exists() && (newData.val() != null && newData.child('id').val() + '' === auth.id)) || ($user_index ===  auth.id)"
      }

    }

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue - take a look at http://plnkr.co/edit/UkfRDGIZrJQXnaoBUw1P?p=preview for an example. Could you email support@firebase.com so we can debug further? It could be a bug specific to your Firebase.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the same problem I'm having with the example provided at http://plnkr.co/edit/UkfRDGIZrJQXnaoBUw1P?p=preview.  I simply added an 'id' attribute with an integer:  var index = fireIndex.create({id: 1, name: document.getElementById("newuser").value}); I'm doing this because I need to match that id with the one generated by FirebaseSimpleLogin (using Email), so that any index can be updated directly if the user needs to update it (such as changing last or first name). I have also submitted an email to support@firebase.com.

Comment: Thanks - let's follow up via support email - I suspect the issue is caused by using 'id' as the property which is treated specially by Backfire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution provided by Firebase:

Thanks for the repro. That’s Firebases array inference at work (and you’ll see the issue even without using Backfire). Whenever Firebase sees keys that are numeric, it assumes that you want the data as an array instead of just an object. In this particular case, since there is only key named ‘1’ it assumes it’s an array, and the value at index 0 is null (all values in Firebase that aren’t set are null).

To work around this, you can do a few things:

- Switch to using IDs generated by push() – or in the case of Backfire – Backbone.Firebase.Collection.add.
- Prefix user ID with a string like ‘-’ or ‘:’ so that array interpretation doesn’t kick in.
- Adjust your code so that you interpret the value as an array and skip over null values.

Hope this helps!